# Is it possible to "upsert" a message in Kafka using Kafka Connect?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, upsert, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent 3.3.0. I am using `jdbc-source-connector` to insert messages into Kafka from my Oracle table. This works fine.
I would like to check if "upsert" is possible.

I mean, if I have a student table, having 3 columns `id`(number), `name`(varchar2), and `last_modified`(timestamp). Whenever I insert new row, it will be pushed to Kafka (using timestamp+auto increment fields). But when I update the row, corresponding message in Kafka should be updated.

The `id` of my table should become they `key` of corresponding Kafka message. My primary key (id) will remain constant as a reference.
The Timestamp field will get updated every time when the row is updated.

Is this possible? Or deleting existing record in Kafka and inserting the new one.

Comment: If you want update events, you should consider using a CDC based solution. https://debezium.io/blog/2018/07/19/advantages-of-log-based-change-data-capture/ Otherwise, you are just re-polling the entire row, not knowing what has changed or not... And you cannot edit/delete records in Kafka anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> But when i update the row, corresponding message in Kafka should be updated

This isn't possible as Kafka is, by design, append-only, and immutable.

The best you would get is either querying all rows by some `last_modified` column, or hook in a CDC solution such as Oracle GoldenGate or the [alpha Debezium solution](https://debezium.io/blog/2018/07/26/debezium-0-9-0-alpha1-released/) that would capture the single UPDATE event on the database and append a brand new record on the Kafka topic.

If you want to de-dupe your database records in Kafka (find the message with the max `last_modified` within a window of time), you can use Kafka Streams or KSQL to perform that type of post-process filtering.

If you are using compacted Kafka topics, and inserting the your database key as the Kafka message key, then after compaction, then the latest appended message will persist, and the previous message with the same key will be dropped, not updated

Comment: Ok. I am getting the updated rows from Kafka every time since i refer the last_modified column. But how it will be, if i insert a message into Kafka with same message key of the existing entry in Kafka? Will it get replaced?

Comment: The message is always appended, not replaced, as mentioned. Only if you have compacted topics will be old keys be removed after a period of time

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007